# why is this flask not showing standard message according to my code?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

my rest service sits at http://127.0.0.1:5000, but when i launch it, it gives me 404:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

why is that? I want my server to show some status msg like 'service ready'.

The actual function that i will use is accessible and works, when i press 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/parser/tengrinews' and hit enter it outputs the msg i coded in the function in my flask app:

```
[
  "parsing this website :", 
  "tengrinews"
]
```

the main code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

#this is my std method i can't see
@app.route("/http://127.0.0.1:5000/", methods = ['GET'])
def main():
    return jsonify('service is ready')

@app.route("/parser/<string:website>", methods = ['GET'])
def parse(website):    
    return jsonify("parsing this website :", website   )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line -

`@app.route("/http://127.0.0.1:5000/", methods = ['GET'])`
to
`@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])`.

Because you have to specify only the extended URL that will be used. The `@app.route` decorator handles the rest for us

Note* (Don't do this. For fun only) -
If you wish to continue to use `@app.route("/http://127.0.0.1:5000/", methods = ['GET'])` then access the endpoint with the url - `http://localhost:5000/http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. You will get the response as `"service is ready"`